# what language uses "fi"

Tags: shell

Saw this script and I am trying to figure out what language is used... it's almost like C but I noticed the fi as a way to close the nested if.

```
function prompt () {
if [ "$noprompt" ] && [ "$#" = "1" ]; then
    if [ "$1" = "yes" ]; then
        echo "DEFAULT: yes"
        return 0
    else
        echo "DEFAULT: no"
        return 1
    fi
fi

while true; do
    echo "Enter \"yes\" or \"no\": "
    read response
    case $response
    in
        Y*) return 0 ;;
        y*) return 0 ;;
        N*) return 1 ;;
        n*) return 1 ;;
        *)
    esac
done
}
```

Comment: Shell script. Probably sh, bash, or similar

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The piece of code is Unix shell. But the answer to the question

> what language uses “fi”

is a bit longer. The usage of *mirrored words*, like `if` and `fi` or `case` and `esac` comes from Algol, for a nice summary see [comparison of languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)). It was [Stephen Bourne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Bourne) who carried this from Algol to the Unix shell, he worked first on Algol, later on `sh` and `adb` of the early Unix systems. He favored this syntax so much that even the `C` code he wrote for `sh` and `adb` looks like Algol thanks to a bunch of preprocessor macros. The curious can have a look at the 2.11BSD source code of [source code of sh](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/211bsd/usr/src/bin/sh/main.c.html) or [adb](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/211bsd/usr/src/bin/adb/main.c.html). It compiles as C after all. So even in C one can find `FI` when going back a long way in history.

Answer (score 12):

Those are used by Unix Shell Scripts... 
See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/case-esac-statement.htm) and [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html).

Answer (score 5):

That is a script written in [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) shell.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a shell script - bash, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [shell script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) (bash)

Answer (score 1):

`fi` are used by Unix/Linux shells in shell programming,
This is an `if` statement.

```
if [ expression ] 
then 
   Statement(s) to be executed if expression is true 
fi
```

It is run mostly by the `sh` command