# Bash - what's the use of "fi ;;"?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have been searching everywhere for an explanation. Here's a real example taken from the apt-fast.sh script:

```
if [ ! -x /usr/bin/axel ]
then echo "axel is not installed, perform this?(y/n)"
    read ops
    case $ops in
     y) if apt-get install axel -y --force-yes
           then echo "axel installed"
        else echo "unable to install the axel. you are using sudo?" ; exit
        fi ;;
     n) echo "not possible usage apt-fast" ; exit ;;
    esac
fi
```

What's the use of `"fi ;;"` in the middle of the `if` block?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what language uses "fi"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310008/what-language-uses-fi)

Comment: @ajreal No, that question doesn't explain what the use of "fi ;;" is.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

`fi` closes the `if` statement, while `;;` closes the current entry in the `case` statement.

Comment: According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310008/what-language-uses-fi), a similar rule also applies to `case` statements, where `esac` should be used to close the `case` statement. This makes me wonder:

1. What rules apply to `while` and `for` statements? Should `elihw` and/or `rof` (which is basicly `while` and `for` spelled backwards) be used to close such statements?

2. And what about `elif` statements? With a similar backwards approach, the corresponding word would be `file`, which I think could be dangerously misinterpretable, at least by human eyes.

Comment: I suggest you read Brian Kernighan's "UNIX A History and a Memoir" for insight in why you get if/fi, but while-do/done.

Answer (score 16):

The `fi` is to close the if-block in the `y)` case statement and the `;;` is used to end the `y)` case.

Answer (score 11):

`fi` terminates the preceding `if`, while `;;` terminates the `y)` case in the `case...esac`.

Answer (score 9):

`fi` closes the `if` statement opened 3 lines up. `;;` closes the case opened by `y)`.